# Cannot create new VS 2013 Website solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When I create a new Website solution using VS 2013 with .Net 4.5 and try to build it I get multiple error messages, including many of the form "The type or namespace name ', where  is Optimization, Owin, ASpNet, and many others. If I try to add System.Web.Optimization via Nuget it tells me that it is already installed. I get the same result with Owin. What can I do about these errors?
[image]

Comment: attach the screenshot of errors

Comment: Screenshot attached

Comment: You are missing `using...` statements and possibly references in your project.

Comment: I used VS 2013 to create a new web application and tried to build it, and got  the errors shown. I presumed that all required using... and references would be added automatically.

Comment: run `dotnet restore` in package console manager and then build it again.